# Java Return Null When Tried to Get Method

Tags: java

first of all I know this is duplicated question. But I've search and tried from [stackoverflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20get%20set%20return%20null%20site:stackoverflow.com&safe=strict&client=firefox-b-e&sxsrf=ACYBGNRTgle9cDaZQbamsqZPg3kXhUAbOg:1572294555815&ei=m0-3XbCmMcK2rQGvrK6oBg&start=10&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjw3-zT5b_lAhVCWysKHS-WC2UQ8NMDCJEB&biw=1366&bih=654) listed on Google to quora but still cant resolve my Get method still return null.

This is my class **loginModel.java** under package com.hello.model

```
public class loginModel {
  public String username;

  public void setUsername(String username) {
      this.username = username;
  }

  public String getUsername() {
      return this.username;
  }
}
```

This is my **loginView.java** under package com.hello.view

```
import com.hello.model.loginModel;

public class loginView extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  loginModel login = new loginModel();

  public loginView() {
      initComponents();
      this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      loginFunction();
  }

  private void loginFunction(){
    String username = usernameText.getText();
    String password = passwdText.getText();
    String query = "select * from access where username = '" +username+ "' AND password = '" +password+"'";
    databaseConnect db = new databaseConnect();

    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(db.url, db.user, db.password);
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query)) {

        if(rs.next()) {
            if(username.equals(rs.getString("username")) && password.equals(rs.getString("password"))){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "login Success");
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                String privilege = rs.getString("privilege");
                login.setUsername(name);

                menu = new menuView();
                menu.setVisible(true);
                this.setVisible(false);
            }
        } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "username or password incorrect");
            }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I want call my username from **menuView.java** under package com.hello.view after login success

```
import com.hello.model.loginModel;
import com.hello.view.loginView;

public class menuView extends javax.swing.JFrame {    
  private String username;
  loginModel login = new loginModel();

  public menuView() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    initMenu();
  }

  private void initMenu(){
    username = login.getUsername();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, username);
  }
}
```

As per my question when I call Get method from loginModel, messagebox return null.

I've tried:

1. Put system.out.println directly in **loginModel.java**, value return
   and call system.out.println in **menuView.java** at the same time but value return null. How?
2. Send string between jframe with menu = menuView(username) in **loginView.java** and retrieve in **menuView.java**, value return null
3. Using no model and create set string in **loginView** and call it in
   **menuView**, value return null

I need values that I want to use in another class/package/jframe. Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side note: Class names should start with an uppercase letter, otherwise they get confused with method names or variable names.

Comment: Your code can't be compiled because you have a field `loginView login` in your `menuView` class, but later you write `login = new loginModel();`. That is not possible. Also you have a variable/field `login` using in your `loginView` class, but it is nowhere declared. Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have which have been successfully compiled and shows that you get the value `null`.

Comment: Also, you call `login.setUsername(name);` in the class `loginView` but there is no field `login`.

Comment: @Jannik, it was there on loginView, maybe deleted when I edit the format for the first time

Comment: You have two instances of `LoginModel`, which doesn't make sense.  Also, not sure that `setUsername` makes sense. You shouldn't be able to change it after the model is created.  Better supply that information via the constructor.  This would mean that `loginFunction` should be returning the instance of `LoginModel` which the app should be using (or `null` or throw an exception if login failed)

Comment: @Progman, thanks for suggestion. It's my habit, I'll consider it. Btw, it's my second editing, first time I put loginModel login = new loginModel(); but still no value return and change it like that. I've revert to original code

Comment: Your SELECT already compares the username and password. It cannot possibly return a row that doesn't match. You don't need to compare them both yourself again. All you need to know is that `rs.next()` is true, i.e. there was such a row.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, May I know how to do it properly if in my case? 5 hours looking workaround for this, still newbie :D

Comment: @user207421 thanks, but that's not the case :(

Comment: @Fahmi It most certainly is the case that you have redundant code. If that's not what you mean please explain.

Answer (score 1):

I am not well versed in Swing but I can see the problem, just not the exact solution.

Your code creates an instance of loginModel in both the menuView and in loginView.  Then in loginView is sets the name in the instance it has, in in menuView it gets the name from its own instance.

You need to create a single instance of the model and share it between the two views.

In a pojo way I would pass the loginModel to both "views" in a constructor.

```
menu = new menuView(login);
```

And in menuView

```
public menuView(loginModel login) {
    this.login = login;
}
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.openhl7.openhl7.view.loginView.loginFunction(loginView.java:49)

Caught null in LoginView.LoginFunction:
model.setUsername(name);

Answer (score 1):

Your `menuView` instance isn't using the `loginModel` class that you instantiate in `loginView`, it's using the new one you created using `new menuView()` when you initialized the `login` variable in the `menuView` class.  You just need to add a setter method for the `loginModel` attribute in the `menuView` class like this:

```
import com.hello.model.loginModel;
import com.hello.view.loginView;

public class menuView extends javax.swing.JFrame {    
  private String username;
  loginModel login = new loginModel();

  public menuView() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    initMenu();
  }

  private void initMenu(){
    username = login.getUsername();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, username);
  }

  public void setLogin(loginModel loginModel) {
    this.login = loginModel;
  }
}
```

Then call the setter in `loginView.loginFunction` like this:

```
... code before
 login.setUsername(name);
 menu = new menuView();
 menu.setLogin(login);
 menu.setVisible(true);
 this.setVisible(false);
... code after
```

Notice the only changes to your code are the added `setLogin` method on the `menuView` class and the call to `menu.setLogin(login)` in `loginView.loginFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think in stages/steps.  Login is a single step, it has one of two outcomes, success or failure.

Your app needs to perform this step and take appropriate action based on the outcome of the result.

You also need to think about "separation of responsibility" - in this case, it's not really the responsibility of the `loginView` to perform the login operation, it just coordinates the user input.

The responsibility actually falls to the `LoginModel`

```
// Just a custom exception to make it easier to determine 
// what actually went wrong
public class LoginException extends Exception {

    public LoginException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}

// LoginModel ... that "does" stuff
public class LoginModel {

    private String username;
    DatabaseConnect db;

    public LoginModel(DatabaseConnect db) {
        this.db = db;
    }

    // I would consider not doing this.  You need to ask what reasons would
    // the app need this information and expose it only if there is really a 
    // reason to do so
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public boolean isLogedIn() {
        return username != null;
    }

    public void validate(String username, String password) throws SQLException, LoginException {

        String query = "select * from access where username = ? AND password = ?";

        try ( Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(db.url, db.user, db.password);  PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
            st.setString(1, username);
            st.setString(2, password);

            try ( ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery()) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    this.username = username;
                } else {
                    throw new LoginException("Invalid user credentials");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is an overly simplified example, as the actual responsibility for performing the login should fall to the controller, which would then generate the model, but I'm getting ahead of myself.

Because the flow of the app shouldn't be controlled/determined by the login view, the `LoginView` should itself be a dialog.  This way, it can be shown when you need it, it can perform what ever operations it needs and then go away, leaving the rest of the decision making up to who ever called it

```
public class LoginView extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    private LoginModel model;

    public LoginView(LoginModel model) {
        initComponents();
        setModal(true);
        this.model = model;
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    // This will get executed when the user taps some kind of "perform login button"
    private void loginFunction() {
        String username = usernameText.getText();
        String password = passwdText.getText();

        try {
            model.validate(username, password);
            dispose()
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // This should probably be considered a fatal error
            model = null;
            dispose();
        } catch (LoginException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Login vaild");
        }
    }
}
```

This then means you might put it together something like this...

```
DatabaseConnect db = new DatabaseConnect();
LoginModel model = new LoginModel(db);

LoginView loginView = new LoginView(model);
// Because we're using a modal dialog, the code execution will wait here
// till the window is disposed/closed
loginView.setVisible(true);

if (loginView.model != null) {
    // model is now valid and can continue to be used
    // in what ever fashion you need
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fatal Error");
}
```

This takes you a step closer to a more decoupled solution, where you feed information to the classes when they need it, rather than the classes making decisions about what they should create/use.

It also moves you a step closer to re-usable classes, as they do their specific job and nothing more.

You might find taking the time to read up on "model-view-controller" will help you better understand this approach